# Z3py: Add value to computed result and make another check

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to solve the following example with `Z3`:

```
input = 0
if input < 5:
    var v1 = 5
    input += v1
    input *= v1

if input > 5:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

How do I turn this logic into `Z3`? This is what I have so far.

```
input = Int("input")
v1 = Int("v1")

solver = Solver()
solver.add(v1 == 5)
solver.add(input < 5)

solver.check()
model = solver.model()
for d in model.decls():
    # prints:
    #   "input = 4"
    #   "v1 = 5"
    print ("%s = %s" % (d.name(), model[d]))
```

How do I add 5 to input and multiple input with 5 that I can later check if it's greater than 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard technique for modeling such imperative programs is to convert it to SSA (static single assignment) form, essentially by duplicating each assigned variable at each position. For details, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

Based on this idea, I'd model your program as follows:

```py
from z3 import *

v1 = Int('v1')

input0, input1, input2 = Ints('input0 input1 input2')

solver = Solver()

solver.add(input0 == 0)
solver.add(Implies(input0 < 5, v1 == 5))
solver.add(input1 == If(input0 < 5, input0 + v1, input0))
solver.add(input2 == If(input0 < 5, input1 * v1, input1))

result = Bool('result')
solver.add(result == (input2 > 5))

print(solver.check())
m = solver.model()
print ("input  = %s" % m[input2])
print ("v1     = %s" % m[v1])
print ("result = %s" % m[result])
```

When run, this prints:

```
sat
input  = 25
v1     = 5
result = True
```

which shows the final values of the variables involved and the returned value.