# Z3Py: How do I set boolean variable declared in List?

Tags: z3, z3py

I have created a list of boolean variables like below:

```
lk=[Bool("a_0"), Bool("a_1"), Bool("a_2")]
```

I would like to initialize all these boolean variables to `False`.
If I write

```
for i in lk: i=False
```

It does not set variables `a_0, a_1, a_2` to `False`.

How can I assign `True` or `False` values to variables declared in List in Z3Py? Help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be:

```py
from z3 import *

lk = [Bool("a_0"), Bool("a_1"), Bool("a_2")]

s = Solver()

for i in lk:
  s.add(i == False)

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Note that we directly tell the solver that you want these variables to be set to `False` via the `s.add` calls. When I run this I get:

```
sat
[a_0 = False, a_1 = False, a_2 = False]
```

However, I suspect your actual intention is to "initialize" these variables, and later on change their value. This is *not* possible in z3py; you should not think of the values `a_0`, `a_1`, etc., as mutable variables like you'd have in regular Python: z3py is a "functional programming" environment, i.e., you cannot mutate declared variables. (Of course, you can assert constraints about them.)

If your intention is to model a programming language, where variables get declared, initialized, and mutated; you first have to convert to the so called SSA (static single assignment) form, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

There are other questions on stack-overflow that deal with similar issues. See this one, for instance: [Z3py: Add value to computed result and make another check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888293/z3py-add-value-to-computed-result-and-make-another-check/64889125#64889125)

Comment: Thanks alias. Your answer solved my issue.